# How to add multiple data from listview to database sql server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this project that need to add records from the list view to the database

This is the aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvPODetails" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltRefNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PODetailNo") %>' Visible="false" />
                        <%# Eval("ProductName")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Price", "{0: #,###.00}") %>
                </td>
                <td><%# Eval("DesiredQuantity") %></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" type="number" Text='<%# Eval("DesiredQuantity") %>' class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><%# Eval("POAmount", "{0: #,###.00}") %></td>
               <td><%# Eval("POAmount", "{0: #,###.00}") %></td>
               <td>

                </td>
            </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><h2 class="text-center">No records found.</h2></td>
        </tr>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This is the cs:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  int ProductQuantity;
    string ProductName;

    ProductName = Convert.ToString(lvPODetails.FindControl("ltRefNo"));
    ProductQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(lvPODetails.FindControl("txtQuantity"));
}
```

I can't seem to get the right way to find ltRefNo and txtQuantity.
Or is the aspx wrong at all?

Comment: This is not the right way to do. see the basic example here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44070/Insert-a-new-record-using-ListView-with-a-GridView

Comment: I was looking thru the guide that you have sent. Will this add multiple row in one click?

Comment: dude, I already told this one is basic example. to learn anything start with basic thing. and ya u can play with ItemCommand Event. Set command name and run your code.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for fixing the form, but how do I add it in a click event outside the list view

Comment: on button click event, loop thru the listitems and in foreach loop do insert opration.

Comment: could you give me an example, on how I can foreach loop item from a listview. I could not locate them using .FindControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here the sample code,

```
if(e.CommandName == "SaveAll")
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in ListViewName.Items)
    {
      // Code goes here. You can find control using  e.Item.Findcontrol
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I locate those textbox from the listview?

Comment: see in foreach loop, try to find control using item object. TextBox txt = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity");

Comment: I tried the literal, this error show No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal to a known managed provider native type.

Answer (score 0):

use `itemcommand` in listview

```
protected void lvPODetails_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName)
    {
         var txtquentity = e.Item.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to add the multiple row in one click